4 display modes across 3 displays and 2 computers
I have a laptop and a PC and three displays.  I need to switch between the computers and the displays and sometimes be working in each computer simultaneously.  I have already tried a 4 by 4 by 4 KVM TESmart switch but it only had two display modes.  All three monitors for one computer or 1 monitor per computer (Even though I only have 2).
I think I need 4 display modes.  What I want to be able to do is have all displays for the PC or for the laptop.  Or PC Display 1 & Display 2 and Laptop with Display 3.  Or PC Display 1 and Laptop with Display 2 & Display 3.  Any ideas would be appreciated.
